# Error: inreplace failed while installling with homebrew?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, treetagger

I would like to install [treetagger](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) in OS X. In order to make it easier I tried to search if this is possible with Homebrew. So I look at the web and found this [formula](https://github.com/pepijnkokke/homebrew-compling/blob/master/tree-tagger.rb) from pepijnkokke user. Next, I tried to install treetagger as follows:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-User-2:~$ brew install /Users/user/Downloads/tree-tagger.rb
```

However, I got the following error:

```
==> Installing dependencies for tree-tagger: openssl, wget
==> Installing tree-tagger dependency: openssl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2g.el_capitan.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2g.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2g: 1,678 files, 12.0M
==> Installing tree-tagger dependency: wget
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/wget-1.17.1.el_capitan.bot
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring wget-1.17.1.el_capitan.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.17.1: 9 files, 1.5M
==> Installing tree-tagger
==> Downloading http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/tr
######################################################################## 100.0%
Warning: SHA1 support is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Please switch this formula to SHA256.
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: d823320b718eb41a5b4fef449a711307caaf0d88
Actual: 340e09912101acd996642eeed8f623315fa6d672
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tree-tagger-3.2.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I removed the above file and the sha line (sha1 "d823320b718eb41a5b4fef449a711307caaf0d88") and tried again. Nevertheless I got this:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User-2:~$ brew install /Users/user/Downloads/tree-tagger.rb==> Downloading http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/tr
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> wget http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/tagger-sc
==> wget http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/english-p
==> wget http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/english-c
==> wget http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/install-t
==> chmod +x ./install-tagger.sh
==> ./install-tagger.sh
Error: inreplace failed
cmd/chunker-read-lemma.perl:
  expected replacement of /BIN=.*/ with "BIN=/usr/local/Cellar/tree-tagger/3.2/libexec/bin"
  expected replacement of /CMD=.*/ with "CMD=/usr/local/Cellar/tree-tagger/3.2/libexec/cmd"
  expected replacement of /LIB=.*/ with "LIB=/usr/local/Cellar/tree-tagger/3.2/libexec/lib"
```

Any idea of how to install treetagger with homebrew?.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried installing `openssl` via homebrew?

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
brew install treehugger
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just install it the normal way as mentioned in the document?

The following steps are necessary to install the TreeTagger (see below for the Windows version). Download the files by right-clicking on the link. Then select "save file as". All files should be stored in the same directory.

- Download the tagger package for your system (PC-Linux, Mac OS-X
  (Intel-CPU), PC-Linux (version for older kernels)).

  Download the tagging scripts into the same directory.

  Download the installation script install-tagger.sh.

  Download the parameter files for the languages you want to process.

  Open a terminal window and run the installation script in the
  directory where you have downloaded the files:

  sh install-tagger.sh

  Make a test, e.g. echo 'Hello world!' | cmd/tree-tagger-english

You might want to add ~/homebrew-compling/cmd and ~/homebrew-compling/bin to the PATH variable so that you do not need to specify the full path to run the tagging scripts.

This worked for me fine!